# Add UIActionsheet into UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uialertview, uiactionsheet

How can i add uiactionsheet into uialertview ???
I am also add tableview into alertview and also want to add actionsheet which having four buttons
when i wrote these code its gives error

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Preferences"
                                                    message:@"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    UITableView *myView = [[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 40, 264, 150)
                                                        style:UITableViewStylePlain] autorelease];
    myView.delegate = self;
    myView.dataSource = self;



    [alert addSubview:myView];

   NSString *actionSheetTitle = @"Action Sheet Demo"; //Action Sheet Title
   NSString *destructiveTitle = @"Destructive Button"; //Action Sheet Button Titles
   NSString *other1 = @"Other Button 1";
   NSString *other2 = @"Other Button 2";
   NSString *other3 = @"Other Button 3";
   NSString *cancelTitle = @"Cancel Button";


   UIActionSheet *actionSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:actionSheetTitle
                                                            delegate:self
                                                   cancelButtonTitle:cancelTitle
                                              destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveTitle
                                                   otherButtonTitles:other1, other2, other3, nil];

   UIView *tempView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 250, alert.frame.size.width, 250)];
   tempView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
   tempView.clipsToBounds = YES;
   [alert addSubview:tempView];

   [alert addSubview:actionSheet];
  [alert show];
    [actionSheet showInView:tempView];
     [myView reloadData];
```

Tableview completely add but actionsheet will not add.
So is there any solution available????

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Old question, but I would recommend [CXAlertView](https://github.com/ChrisXu1221/CXAlertView) for anyone getting here through google

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for your contribution. While a link to an external resource can be helpful, to constitute a real answers it often requires context. Please see [answer], specifically the section **Provide context for links**. In this case, explain how the OP would use this to solve their problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend not using an alert and simply animate a view on screen to display what you want since an alert has a specific purpose. It's much easier than it sounds.